# Как ходить по ландшафту?

Tags: three.js, webgl

В ThreeJS с помощью функции `PlaneGeometry` можно создать плоскость по которой можно ходить. Ходьба имитируется движением камеры. Я создал ландшафт по карте высот и загрузил на сцену.

Как мне теперь организовать передвижение по этому ландшафту? Как организовать тоже самое для объектов, которыми я не управляю непосредственно?

Comment: Посмотрите экзамплы к фреймворку на гитхабе(например webgl_skinning_simple.html), там есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: при рендеринге `camera.position.y = 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть контроллер, который эмулирует камеру от первого лица, как в играх.  `FirstPersonControls` лежить в `github- e examples/js/controls`